# Edit session after session_write_close();

Tags: php

Is following syntax right to edit a session after session_write_close()?

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['val']);
session_write_close();
// ...some code here
// edit session
$_SESSION['val']= 'test';
session_write_close();
?>
```

What is the best syntax to do everything?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: It seems to work, but I would like to know if this solution is the best.

Comment: You can do whatever you want to $_SESSION after session_write_close(), it simply will not be saved when the script exits, and will be lost. s_w_c() basically writes out the CURRENT contents of the session to the session file, then releases the lock on that file.

Comment: So I have to remove the first session_write_close()?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

99.9% of the time, you should never need to use `session_write_close()` at all.

If all you want to do is make changes to the session data, you don't *need* to use `session_write_close()`, because PHP does a `session_write_close()` for you anyway when your program ends. All you need to do is set your session data into `$_SESSION`, and PHP will do the rest for you.

The only time you actually need to use `session_write_close()` explicitly is if you are having problems with session locking due to your program having excessively long running time. But in that case, you would probably be better off fixing the program so it runs quicker rather than messing around with `session_write_close()`.

Comment: `99.9% of the time, you should never need to use session_write_close() at all.` That's an incorrect statement. If you are sending multiple ajax requests to your PHP script which requires session (which is much common), they can start becoming a bottleneck. Consider a scenario, each request take 500ms and I am sending 10 requests. That means It will take 5.5 seconds to complete last request even if it requires 500ms of  processing.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient...

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['val']);

// ...some code here
// edit session
$_SESSION['val']= 'test';
```

Because changing `$_SESSION` directly write the data! **edit** at the end of the script

To complete, when you use `session_write_close()`, you close the SESSION! So you can't use `$_SESSION` while you don't put another `session_start()`... That was my idea!

Comment: No, it doesn't.  However, the session *is* automatically saved at the end of a script, so it's true that you don't need to explicitly close the session.